# Bootstrap Carousel same image size (Exception offset)

Tags: javascript, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, autoresize

I am getting an exception in javascript, and I know this is because of image size..

I want my carousel to have a fixed size for the images, and to auto adjust/resize the image (if it gets distorted or pixelized its not a problem, I just want the full image occupying the size of the carousel.

I have been playing with max-width and width and couldn't get it work.
I want this to be responsive also.

**Here is my html code:**

```
<div id="myCarousel" style="display: block;" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="carouselIndicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" id="carouselData" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
          <h3>Random text 1</h3>
          <p>Random text 2</p>
          <img src="imageurl.png" alt="">
       </div>
        <div class="item">
              <h3>Random text 3</h3>
              <p>Random text 4</p>
              <img class="tales" src="imagelink.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Here is javascript exception (The slider doesnt work):**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Comment: can you show the javascript?

Comment: Which one? I am not using any javascript file for this,  just built in bootstrap.min.css

Comment: It may just be a problem in bootstrap. I cant find anything, maybe someone else can.

Comment: Thank you, do you know by the way how to adjust images to the same size using this html? I tried something from other answers and none worked...  Maybe I am doing something wrong.  Thanks for ur input

Comment: You could try an absolute position(position:absolute;). Also did you try to use percentages instead of pixels or whatever?

Comment: It's fixed, thank you!

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Updating Bootstrap and jQuery to last version using NuGet and then applying the following css rules on the accepted answer made it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I got it fixed finnaly.

**Using the following CSS Style:**

```
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
 .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
     display: block;
     width:100%;
     height: 350px !important;
 }
```

My bootstrap carousel now has a fixed height, and then the images are always resized to match the total width of carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One With Width And Height and Jquery

```
  <div class="container">
  <h2> Carousel </h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li class="item1 "></li>
  <li class="item2"></li>

  </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

  <div class="item active">
    <img src="l.jpg" alt="test" width="400" height="300">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>kkk</p>
    </div>
   </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="l.jpg" alt="test" width="400" height="300">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>kk</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

 <!--  controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

and also add some jquery

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
//  Carousel
$("#myCarousel").carousel();

//  Carousel Indicators
$(".item1").click(function(){
    $("#myCarousel").carousel(0);
});
$(".item2").click(function(){
    $("#myCarousel").carousel(1);
});


//  Controls
$(".left").click(function(){
    $("#myCarousel").carousel("prev");
});
$(".right").click(function(){
    $("#myCarousel").carousel("next");
});
 });
  </script>
```